# Shouldn't there be a `resource-recommendation` tag?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

While reading the questions on the main page I noticed https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/3520/looking-for-books-focusing-on-tests-and-quizzes-relating-to-first-aid-diagnose . It asks for recommendation of books. Now, wouldn't it be better if it had been tagged with [resource-recommendation](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resource-recommendation) or [recommendation](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recommendation) that are prevalent in other sites like Phys. SE, Chem. SE etcetera? Irrespective of being on-topic or off-topic, these sort of queries should be categorised under [recommendation](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recommendation).

So, is there any sort of this tag existing? If so, can anyone mention it?

And if there is not, may I request for the [resource-recommendation](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resource-recommendation) tag? Any sort of opinion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I would say recommendation questions like that are bad as the recommendations can go out of date and no longer be a good one.

Because in general recommendation questions are bad a tag should not be created for them because it give the false impression that they are allowed.

It all boils down to the fact that a tag should not be created just because it can be.

Answer (score 1):

I think that resource recommendation should be on topic (and that therefore there should be a tag for it):

- Good resources don't disappear so quickly (and are most likely mirrored anyway).
- Quite a few Stack Exchange websites accept them, and it often leads to interesting answers.

Comment: Damn, I forgot I asked this ;P

Answer (score 0):

Agreeing with what @JoeW said, do we have any reason to think these questions are on topic to begin with? I thought such questions were discouraged across the SE platform.

I think we'd need to make the argument that health has a special enough case to include them.  Otherwise I don't want to make a tag for something that should always be deleted.

Comment: So, Phys SE, Chem SE all did wrong?

Comment: @user36790 I'm not part of those communities, but possibly.  It doesn't really matter in my mind, because each group would have to make a strong argument as to why such questions should be on topic.  Perhaps those groups have made such an argument and it could be copied here.

Comment: Recently there has been a serious argument on whether they should be on-topic or off-topic; more including I were inclined on making them closed on the ground that would be primarily opinion-based. But that's another issue. What I wanted is to include the tag.

Comment: @user36790 I can't find that discussion in the recent Health.meta posts, but if it's existing somewhere else in the network it would be useful to include a link to it in your question.  I would think that we should settle that issue first before making a tag.  Other wise it might turn into a tag-&-delete scenario.

Comment: I'm talking about this Phys SE meta post [Book recommendations: On-topic, on-topic but community wiki, or off-topic?](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7039/book-recommendations-on-topic-on-topic-but-community-wiki-or-off-topic).

Comment: They should apply here also. BTW, no matter be it closed or open, the tag does exist.

Comment: I think making them not [shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) would be difficult, but might be ok as community handled wiki's.  I think it's a seperate meta-question, and I'm just sharing my opinion against allowing book recommendations, and therefore the tag as well.

Answer (score 0):

The question mentioned here was closed as it was opinion-based and is now deleted. But, for future use, for non opinion-based questions like this, which can exist ([there are some](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request)) I feel **reference-request** may be better than resource-recommendation.

A recommendation is opinion based but a request would be for something which is definitely reputable.

Neither has been created as of yet, but if [resource-recommendation](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resource-recommendation) is ever created, I feel it and [resource-request](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resource-request) should be synonyms of [reference-request](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request)

Comment: You wrote this 11 hours ago and I just came here looking for whether or not someone had suggest a reference-request tag! I'm looking for a video in which the Massouh sign for appendicitis is tested, to see how it is done. I don't know if this question would be well-received though? I did look for videos on youtube and surprisingly didn't find anything yet.

Comment: user1271772 - If your question is useful to the community, whether or be students only, or anyone; plus you provide details as to how you tried to find the reference material yourself, I see no problem asking such a question.